# Как найти пользователя используя библиотеку ldap3?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

Я пишу TelegramBot'а для автоматической смены пароля доменного пользователя, т.е. я получаю от него логин для входа, обычно он в формате ФамилияИ(ПупкинВ). И далее мне необходимо узнать есть ли такой логин в ActiveDirectory и поставить дефолтный пароль - 123456 с флагом смены пароля при следующем входе.

Для реализации всего этого, я нашла два варианта:

1. Команды ActiveDirectory(dsquery, dsmod, ..)
2. Библиотека ldap3

В обоих случаях проблема поиска по логину(вроде это и есть samid/samacountname)

По второму варианту, использовала вот этот пример https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adpasswd

Или я чего-то не знаю, или что-то не так делаю, но очень надеюсь на вашу помощь в следующих вопросах:

1. Как найти пользователя по его логину?
2. Если реализовывать через ldap, как при смене пароля можно поставить флаг "сменить пароль при входе"?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, в ходе бесконечных попыток и гуглинга у меня получилось сделать.

С поиском была проблема используемой библиотеки в примере, параметры там и в установленной мною немного отличаются. 
Вот функция для поиска по логину, которая возвращает DN:

```
    def findUser(login):
        """
        param name: login
        return: dn of user
        """
        userDN = None
        base = "CN=my,CN=domain" 
        search_filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))'% (login)
        x = conn.search(base, search_filter,attributes=['distinguishedName'])
        if x != False:
            userDN = conn.response[0]['attributes']['distinguishedName']
        conn.unbind()
        return userDN
```

Для смены пароля пришлось извратится, т.к. так  и не поняла как поменять пароль через ldap.modify()

Так как Active Directory находится на другом сервере установила утилиту PSExec, которая позволяет удаленно управлять компьютером, в первую очередь через командную строку. Команда AD dsmod user просит именно DN для смены пароля, что у меня и получилось достать в первой части. Таким образом устанавливаем соединение и запускаем команду:

```
    def changepass(login, newpass):
        """
        :param login: user's login
        :param newpass: default password, usually 123456
        """
        dn = findUser(login)
        reset_cmd = 'dsmod user "{dn}" -pwd {newpass} -mustchpwd yes'.format(dn = dn, 
                                                   newpass = newpass)

        app = "cmd /C {0}".format(reset_cmd)

        cmd = "{exe} \\\\{host} -u {domain}\\{user} -p {password} {app}".format(
                                    exe = config['psexec'], 
                                    host = config['host'],
                                    domain = config['domain'],
                                    user = config['user'],
                                    password = config['secret'],
                                    app = app)
        res = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
```

Вот, надеюсь кому-нибудь это поможет.